# Android text alignment based on character's index

Tags: android, text, alignment

I have a seemingly simple task in **Android**, which turned out to be quite complex.
I have multiple strings, and I want each string to be **centered based on a character in a specific position in that string**. For example "azcde" should be centered on a character in index 1 ("z" in this case), "trxdsf" should be centered on a character in index 2 ("x" in this case), ...

Below is an example.

[image]

The problem is that characters vary in size (e.g. "i" is much thinner than "m")...

Can this be done in TextView or custom View?

Comment: Out of the top of my head, I don't think it's possible (also I don't think is a simple task). Android layout framework is built for responsiveness, and what you're suggesting would be impossible to maintain over many different screen sizes, layouts, and last but not least font sizes (user can always change this). You should really consider why would you want such a complicated text imho.

Comment: A workaround would be to split each line into 3 parts, say 'left', 'red' (one letter), and 'right'. Now you should center all the reds one below the other, possibly using a hidden char as placeholder. Then you would set the left part aligned left to the red, and the right part aligned right. But I wouldn't really go this way, strongly discouraged.

Comment: Thank for response.The lines I am showing in the image are just the representation of the words that show one after the other in the same TextView (only one word is visible at any moment).

Comment: Thanks for response. The words shown in my image are supposed to be all in the single TextView (one linie). So only one of those words is shown in the TextView at any moment, one following after another.

Your suggestion is what I tied before, but the problem is that I can't find a way to insert "left" part before the the "red" part because it moves the "red" part.

Comment: Of course it doesn't. When you specify an xml layout, elements are drawn top to bottom. Like I said, inside a RelativeLayout you first specify the TextView with id 'red1' (red char of line 1), and align it to some hidden value you place somewhere (say middle of the parent, for a start); after which you specify the TextView with id 'right1' and align it on the right of red1 (using align_left property); alike, now specify TextView with id 'left1' and align it on the left of red1 (using align_right property). It should work.

Comment: Still, I wouldn't go this way, you should really think about your motivation. It would be nice if you would answer me why you really want to have it that way, because you're entering some kind of hell at this moment, so you should really think it through. If you're a good developer, you should be able to evaluate when a given requirement makes sense, and when it doesn't make much sense, because you'll have to maintain this hell of a code.

Comment: Sorry for late response. It's about Spritz reader - you can find short demo here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ky8DP55YEO0
I agree with you - I don't like hacks either...

Comment: Eventually I solved the problem by creating custom View and drawing text on it.

Comment: I used StaticLayout, TextPaint and measureText method on TextPaint.